How to transpose horizontal data into vertical form with date match using formula
I have been trying to transpose data from a horizontal list (Table A) into vertical set (Table B) with the condition of date and enroll match.
Table A

Table B

I would like to have one person data at a time. For example, one enroll data will be manually put in the Cell K2; this should result into getting shift data returned into Column N correspondingly.
I use MS Excel 2019 version.
Thanks in advance!

Here is one way of doing this:

Solution is based on OP's post which is clearly written:
I use MS Excel 2019 version.




• Formula used in cell B7
=VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$B$4,2,0)


• Formula used in cell C7 --> This can be made dynamic based on Enroll and Name as well.
=TRANSPOSE(C1:I1)


• Formula used in cell D7
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$I$4,MATCH(1,($A$7=$A$2:$A$4)*($B$7=$B$2:$B$4),0),MATCH($C7,$C$1:$I$1,0)),"")



Just working great! Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya !
P.S. I just had to use    Ctrl+Shift+Enter during the use of    TRANSPOSE() and
INDEX()/MATCH() formula used in Cell C7 & D7.
Thanks again!

Here's a possible solution:
=IFNA(HSTACK(XLOOKUP(A7,A2:A4,B2:B4),TOCOL(C1:I1),TOCOL(XLOOKUP(A7,A2:A4,C2:I4))),"")


If you want to return all the data in that format:
=DROP(REDUCE(0,A2:A4,LAMBDA(a,c,IFNA(VSTACK(a,HSTACK(c,
   XLOOKUP(c,A2:A4,B2:B4),TOCOL(C1:I1),TOCOL(XLOOKUP(c,A2:A4,C2:I4)))),""))),1)



Thanks for helping me out @z..
The solution your provided seems not functioning as I use MS Excel 2019 version.
Any other solution for older versions of excel please !!!

whoops, I missed that part! But someone else got you covered. Cheers.
